# Clicking Index in table of contents gets last chapter instead of Index

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, indexing

Here is a minimum working example:

```
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red!50!black}}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
%\frontmatter

\Large \textsc{Reasonable Book}

\tableofcontents

%\mainmatter

\chapter{One}   
Some text \textbf{indexed}\index{indexed}   

%\backmatter
\chapter{FDL}
The purpose of this License 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}   
\printindex
\end{document}
```

When I click on `Index`in the `table of contents` I get `Chapter 2 FDL` instead of `Index`. (Originally, FDL was in backmatter but that did not seem to be where the problem is so here I commented all three "matters" out.)

Comment: the `\addcontentsline` for the index has to be on the same page as the start of the index.  insert a line `\newpage` before it, just to make sure.  (and keep the blank line above it.)

Comment: @barbara beeton `\newpage` alone did not do it for me. But with `\phantomsection` it did, texhack notwithstanding, More below, though.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't thinking about clicking on the link; i was thinking more that the page number would be wrong, and that's what `\newpage` was intended to correct.  and yes, `\phnatomsection` is certainly needed to get a correct hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` will provide the `Index` in the `ToC` without a manual `\addcontentsline`. (The `nottoc` is the option if the `ToC` itself shouldn't be listed additionally in the `ToC`.)

This has to be followed by a `\newpage\phantomsection` to be on the safe side.

```
   % !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red!50!black}}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
%\frontmatter

\Large \textsc{Reasonable Book}

\tableofcontents

%\mainmatter

\chapter{One}   
Some text \textbf{indexed}\index{indexed}   

%\backmatter
\chapter{FDL}
The purpose of this License 

%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}   

\newpage
\phantomsection
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Another solution, with `imakeidx` -- this is shorter and cleaner, in my point of view. An addition, it does automatically generate the index (if `\write18` is enabled`and allows for splitted/multiple indexes etc.) Just say`\makeindex[intoc]

```
   % !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red!50!black}}

\makeindex[intoc]
\begin{document}
%\frontmatter

\Large \textsc{Reasonable Book}

\tableofcontents

%\mainmatter

\chapter{One}   
Some text \textbf{indexed}\index{indexed}   

%\backmatter
\chapter{FDL}
The purpose of this License 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1.  As noted above, `\newpage` along with `\phantomsection` worked for me _without_ the `tocbibind package`. 2. In the magnum opus, which uses the Oberdiek "quick and dirty hack" to allow coexistence with showidx, it still works but here the index page starts with the first entry without showing the title. 3. The `tocbibind` package does not improve on this in the magnum opus. **4.** The imakeidx package seems to conflict with the Oberdiek "quick and dirty hack". (TeX capacity exceeded). I have a mwe that I can post in another question if you are interested.

Comment: @schremmer: I don't have your 'big opus' at hand and whatever 'hacks' are in there, I can't figure out why that fails.

Comment: The magnum opus is at (http://freemathtexts.org/InProgress/RAFv7.1/) and the Oberdiek hack is at (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/fof9f-cln-I). But, as I said, if you want I can post a new question with a mwe.

Comment: Strange: if I open the pdf with preview, all is well!

Comment: @schremmer: I used Adobe Reader...

Comment: So, did the page start with the title, Index, or did the page start with the top entries?